Why does this result work?
Why can I use a substitution in a question like this:
Differentiate $y=x$ with respect to $x^2$
$\frac{ dy }{ dx^2 }$ of $x^2$
Let $x^2$ = $u$
$\frac{ dy }{ du}$ of $\sqrt{u}$
$\frac{ dy }{du}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$
$\frac{dy}{dx^2}$ = $\frac{1}{2x}$
Sorry for the stupid question, I’ve just never seen this done before so would like to know why it works? Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please, use descriptive titles. "Why does this result work?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

The title is bad, but I think it obvious what he wants. He's trying to justify change of variables.

You can validate this with a change of variable algebraically and then apply the usual limit definition of the derivative.

That first substitution of $u$ for $x^2$ is just giving meaning to the idea of "differentiating with respect to $x^2$", Differentiation was defined (at your level) with respect a simple variable, not with respect to another function. The only way to interpret differentiation with respect to a function is to replace the function with another variable. Then you need to express $y$ as a function of this new variable. Since $y = x$ and $u = x^2 = y^2$, we have $y = \sqrt u$ or $y = -\sqrt u$. Your calculation ignores that possibility, and proceeds with only the first case.

You can instead define differentiation with respect to functions: $$\frac{df}{dg}(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{g(x) - g(x_0)}$$However, then you have to redevelop the basic results about derivatives for this definition. But in this case, it provides an easy alternate proof, since $F(x) = \frac 1x$ is continuous except at $0$: $$\frac{dx}{d(x^2)}(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x-x_0}{x^2 - x_0^2} = \lim_{x\to x_0} \dfrac1{\frac{x^2 - x_0^2}{x-x_0}} = \dfrac1{ \lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{x^2 - x_0^2}{x-x_0}} = \dfrac1{\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}} = \frac 1{2x}$$
